# How to choose what axes to plot on in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, plot

How do I select what axes to plot on in pandas?

For example, if I were graphing a countplot in seaborn, I would have written the following:

sns.countplot(females_xt, **ax = axes[0][0]**)

However, I'm not sure how to do this with pandas' plotting capabilities. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

[image]

Comment: the same parameter `ax` in [pandas.dataframe.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), isn't that what you're looking for ?

Comment: oh you're right, I was being an idiot and indexed it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is the same parameter `ax` in [pandas.dataframe.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) like:

```
female_xt.plot(kind ='bar',stacked = True,ax=my_ax)
```